# How does the operator "&" work in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, operator, bitwise-comparison

I was running a trace on one of our test servers when someone did this:

[image]

and one of the queries I could catch in the trace was:

```
declare @UserOption int
select @UserOption=convert(int, c.value) from sys.configurations c where c.name='user options'

SELECT
CAST(@UserOption & 1 AS bit) AS [DisableDefaultConstraintCheck],
CAST(@UserOption & 2 AS bit) AS [ImplicitTransactions],
CAST(@UserOption & 4 AS bit) AS [CursorCloseOnCommit],
CAST(@UserOption & 8 AS bit) AS [AnsiWarnings],
CAST(@UserOption & 16 AS bit) AS [AnsiPadding],
CAST(@UserOption & 32 AS bit) AS [AnsiNulls],
CAST(@UserOption & 64 AS bit) AS [AbortOnArithmeticErrors],
CAST(@UserOption & 128 AS bit) AS [IgnoreArithmeticErrors],
CAST(@UserOption & 256 AS bit) AS [QuotedIdentifier],
CAST(@UserOption & 512 AS bit) AS [NoCount],
CAST(@UserOption & 1024 AS bit) AS [AnsiNullDefaultOn],
CAST(@UserOption & 2048 AS bit) AS [AnsiNullDefaultOff],
CAST(@UserOption & 4096 AS bit) AS [ConcatenateNullYieldsNull],
CAST(@UserOption & 8192 AS bit) AS [NumericRoundAbort],
CAST(@UserOption & 16384 AS bit) AS [AbortTransactionOnError]
```

there is lots of information that can fit in a int if you know -

How does the operator & work?

Comment: The bitwise and operator `&` is documented in the SQL Server Books Online topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx.

Comment: I found this video also very useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qjEkh3P9RE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A single ampersand is the [Bitwise AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) operator. The numbers on either side represent the *value* of one or more bit positions:

```
Actual binary (not BINARY datatype), evaluated from right to left -> 00100010

BIT    Position    Value (Position ^ 2)         "Selected"
0       0                            1                 0
1       1                            2                 2
0       2                            4                 0
0       3                            8                 0
0       4                           16                 0
1       5                           32                32
0       6                           64                 0
0       7                          128                 0
...   ...                          ...               ...
0      62          4611686018427387904                 0
```

Hence, `34` is made up of bitwise values of `2` and `32`.

A very simple example showing that the `&` operator will return whatever value(s) is/are present on *both* sides is:

```sql
SELECT 1 & 1 -- 1
SELECT 1 & 2 -- 0 (because 2 is made up of only 2)
SELECT 1 & 3 -- 1 (because 3 is made up of 1 and 2)

SELECT 2 & 2 -- 2
SELECT 2 & 3 -- 2 (because 3 is made up of 1 and 2)
SELECT 2 & 4 -- 0 (because 4 is made up of only 4)

SELECT 3 &  4 -- 0 (because 3 is made up of 1 and 2, while 4 is made up of only 4)
SELECT 3 &  5 -- 1 (because 3 is made up of 1 and 2, while 5 is made up of 1 and 4)
SELECT 3 & 11 -- 3 (because 3 is made up of 1 and 2, while 11 is made up of 1, 2, and 8)
```

Looking back at the code you posted in the question, you should be able to see how it can be used to determine if one or more bits / flags are "set" within a given value. For example, let's say you want to require that `AnsiPadding` (value = 16), `AnsiNulls` (value = 32) and `QuotedIdentifier` (value = 256) are set to `ON`. You would add up those individual values -- `16 + 32 + 256` -- and then compare the total -- `304` -- with some "current" value, let's say `7000` (values 8 + 16 + 64 + 256 + 512 + 2048 + 4096):

```sql
SELECT 304 & 7000; -- 272
```

The result, `272`, is the combination of `16` and `256`. So if you want to require those 3 options (*additional* options will not adversely affect the result), you would use:

```sql
IF (@options & 304 = 304)
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

As you can see, bitwise operations allow you to extract one or more "options" from one or more "options". But, in the code that you posted, they are just looking for individual options since using `&` with an individual bitwise value will return `0` if not present or that particular bitwise value if present. And the `CAST` to the `BIT` datatype will reduce all of those variations to either `0` (if the `&` yielded a `0`) or `1` (if the `&` yielded anything else).

---

Please note that for the bitwise operators, either side (i.e. *expression*) can be:

> any of the data types of the integer data type category, or the **bit**, or the **binary** or **varbinary** data types.

However, counter-intuitively:

> In a bitwise operation, only one *expression* can be of either **binary** or **varbinary** data type.

That's right: "binary" operations do not work on purely "binary" data ;-). Attempting to do what seems entirely reasonable:

```sql
SELECT 0x03 & 0x0B;
```

will result in the following error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   The data types varbinary and varbinary are incompatible in the '&' operator.

In practical terms, this means that bitwise operations are constrained by the upper-limit of the `BIGINT` datatype (which is 8 bytes / 64 bits). Hence:

- Total bits (i.e. flags / options): **63** (the 64th bit is used for negatives as `BIGINT` is signed)
- Largest individual bit value: **4611686018427387904**  (i.e. `2 ^ 62` ; 62 being the 63rd bit position))
- Largest usable value: **9223372036854775807** (i.e. `(2 ^ 63) - 1` ; all 63 bits present / set to "on")

Meaning: if you need to handle more than 63 flags / options, then you won't be using the `&` operator ;-).

Comment: Awesome explanation with example.

Comment: I love the (var)binary limitation.  And by love, I mean I totally don't understand why such an esoteric limitation should exist, when we're patently intent on comparing binary values.  Why you can't run `SELECT 0x03 & 0x01` is very strange.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Thanks. The answer is even better now :)

Comment: @MaxVernon Exactly. Maybe internally they just had it as a 64 bit INT and didn't want to change it? Also, good idea for that edit. I was in the middle of an edit when you made the change, so I incorporated the idea into my edit.